# My rest api not displaying on the browser after deploying to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I have this task manager rest api which I developed and tested, all went well, after deploying to heroku am trying to view the api on the browser but keep getting this error message "Cannot GET /".

What might be the cause for this error message and what is the solution, I have tried checking my code over and over again but all to no avail. here is the link http://samson-task-manager.herokuapp.com/

Here is one of the task route

```
router.post('/tasks',auth, async (req, res) => {

    const task = new Tasks({
        ...req.body,
        owner: req.user._id
    })

    try {
        await task.save()
        res.status(201).send(task)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

user route

```
router.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
    const user = new User(req.body)

    try {
        await user.save()
        sendWelcomeEmail(user.email, user.name)
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        res.status(201).send({user, token})
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

Comment: what are the routes of api ?

Comment: Is there a GET route for the "/" path?

Answer (score 0):

When you copy and paste  http://samson-task-manager.herokuapp.com/ in the browser you by default are making a **GET** request to **http://samson-task-manager.herokuapp.com/** , and the server is answering you saying that this route doesn't exist. Because you have only declared two routes .../users and .../tasks.

If you try to paste http://samson-task-manager.herokuapp.com/tasks in the browser you will get status 401 and error: Please authenticate, it means that it works correctly.

If you need a better answer, please, give more detailed information.